# Find all possible functions such that..

Tags: functions

We have a function $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N_{>1}$ so that $f(n)+f(n+1)=f(n+2)\cdot f(n+3)-168$

Find all possible functions $f(n)$.
Can you give me a help?

Comment: Is that  $f\colon\{1,2,\ldots\}\to \{2,3,\ldots\}$?

Comment: Such function we are looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer extends [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel)'s answer to show his assumption is correct and, thus, his solutions are the only ones. You have the functional equation of

$$f(n)+f(n+1)=f(n+2)\cdot f(n+3)-168 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Replacing $n$ with $n+1$ gives

$$f(n+1)+f(n+2)=f(n+3)\cdot f(n+4)-168 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Next, \eqref{eq1} - \eqref{eq2} gives

$$f(n) - f(n+2) = f(n+3)(f(n+2) - f(n+4)) \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Replacing $n$ with $n+2$ gives

$$f(n+2) - f(n+4) = f(n+5)(f(n+4) - f(n+6)) \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Substituting \eqref{eq4} into the right side of \eqref{eq3} gives

$$f(n) - f(n+2) = f(n+3)f(n+5)(f(n+4) - f(n+6)) \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

You can continue this procedure to show after $k$ steps that

$$f(n) - f(n+2) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^k f(n+2i+1)\right)(f(n+2k) - f(n+2k+2)) \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

As each $f(n) \ge 2$, then $\prod_{i=1}^k f(n+2i+1) \ge 2^k$, but this becomes arbitrarily large as $k$ increases. However, since $f(n) - f(n+2)$ is a fixed number, it can only be equal to the right side of \eqref{eq6} if it's $0$, which also means that $f(n+2k) - f(n+2k+2) = 0$. In conclusion, $f(n) - f(n+2) = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$.

The set of solutions which Robert's answer provides comes from this, i.e., either $f(n)$ is constant or the values alternate.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  Again, I am a bit confused on WHY   that was possible only if f(n) - f(n+2)=0

Comment: @DritanSkarra I added some more detail that I hope explains to you why it's only possible if $f(n) - f(n+2) = 0$. The key reason is that since all $f(n) \ge 2$, their product has unbounded growth, so it can't be equal to a fixed integer unless this product is multiplied by $0$. Once you have this restriction, Robert's solutions follow from this.

Comment: I got that. Many thanks @JohnOmielan . One last thing from the alternating solutions. I got to the part that f(2k+1)=a and f(2k)=b from which it follows a+b=ab-168. Is there a way how to solve this in N other than by trying.

Comment: @DritanSkarra There is actually a fairly simple way to solve this. From $a+b=ab-168$, you get $b+168=ab-a=a(b-1)$ & then $a=\frac{b+168}{b-1}=\frac{b-1+169}{b-1}=1+\frac{169}{b-1}$. As $a$ is an integer, this means $b-1$ must be a factor of $169=13^2$, so $b-1=1,13,169$ are the only choices. From this, you get the only solutions Robert provided.

Answer (score 1):

A constant solution is $f(n) = 14$ for all $n$.

Other solutions include $f(n) = 2$ for  $n$ odd and $170$ for $n$ even, or the reverse.

EDIT: These solutions come from assuming the solution is constant, or alternating $a$ and $b$, and solving the resulting equation.

I am **not** sure that they are the only solutions, but 
 suspect they are.

Comment: I gave what I believe is a correct proof of your assumption. Please check it and let me know if there are any issues with it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.